AsyncAPI and SpringWolf for Reactor Kafka not showing documentation page

Include details about your goal

Using SpringWolf AsyncAPI, to integrate with Reactor Kafka to see the documentation page.
Just to avoid confusion, this is about SpringWolf AsyncAPI, not SpringDoc, not Swagger.
This is about Reactor Kafka, not apache Kafka, not Spring Kafka
The documentation in question is shown here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DylvTW_ia4Y


Describe what you’ve tried

To achieve such, I went to SpringWolf official guthub page, followed their guide for apache Kafka, spring kafka examples (no Reactor Kafka) and came up with:

Show some code

pom.xml, with dependencies to reactor kafka and springWolf:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0-M3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springwolfreactorkafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>23</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.springwolf</groupId>
            <artifactId>springwolf-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.springwolf</groupId>
            <artifactId>springwolf-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.springwolf</groupId>
            <artifactId>springwolf-asyncapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>


Some boiler plate spring java files, the main and the configuration to make the example reproducible:
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringWolfReactorKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringWolfReactorKafkaApplication.class);
    }

}


package org.example;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class SpringWolfReactorKafkaConsumerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "locahost:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "someidentifier");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "someidentifier");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        final ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(properties);
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singleton("the_topic")));
    }

}


The important file: with the AsyncAPI annotation
package org.example;

import io.github.springwolf.core.asyncapi.annotations.AsyncListener;
import io.github.springwolf.core.asyncapi.annotations.AsyncOperation;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver;

@Service
public final class SpringWolfReactorKafkaService implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver;

    public SpringWolfReactorKafkaService(final KafkaReceiver<String, String> receiver) {
        this.kafkaReceiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    @AsyncListener(operation = @AsyncOperation(channelName = "the_topic"))
    public void run(final String... args) {
        kafkaReceiver.receiveAutoAck().concatMap(message -> message).flatMap(this::processMessages).subscribe();
    }

    private Mono<String> processMessages(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) {
        return Mono.just(consumerRecord).map(oneMessage -> oneMessage.value().toUpperCase());
    }

}


and finally, the application properties:
springwolf.payload.extractable-classes.reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverRecord=1
springwolf.docket.base-package=org.example

springwolf.docket.info.title=${spring.application.name}
springwolf.docket.info.version=1.6.0

springwolf.docket.servers.kafka-server.protocol=kafka
springwolf.docket.servers.kafka-server.host=localhost:9092


Describe expected

With this out-of-the-box project, I hoped to see the doc, as shown in the Youtube video.

Describe actual results

Unfortunately, there is no webpage found at all.

Question

What is missing from the project to get the documentation page?
